# How to set comment into italic strings in Sublime Text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to add some new configuration in Preferences.sublime-setings to make the comment in my java code to italic, what configuration should I add?

Comment: You need to edit the theme file

Comment: yeah,I just don't know what configuration to add to get the comment italic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open the .tmtheme file of the theme you're using:

   - Go to Preferences > Color Scheme and find the checked one.
   - Go to Preferences > Browse Packages and search for that name.
2. Add italics to the comment attributes:

   - Search for `<string>Comment</string>`
   - Inside `<key>settings</key><dict>`, add:

```
        <key>fontStyle</key> 
        <string>italic</string>
```