# Set comments to italic in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I found an answer for [how to do this in ST2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209994/how-to-set-comment-into-italic-strings-in-sublime-text2), but it's not working for me in ST3.

Here's my edit to my theme file:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Comments</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>comment, punctuation.definition.comment</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>italic</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#65737e</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Is there a reason that this works in SL2 and not 3?

Comment: It should work. Does anything else appear as italic in the theme? I believe that Sublime 3 will ignore the italic or bold variant of a font if the width of the characters is different than the width of a character in the normal variant,though. So that might be the issue.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. I've tried this both with Fira Sans and Source Code Pro. I read elsewhere that this might be an issue if the font size isn't set to 9 or 12, so I tried that and no dice either.

Comment: oh apologies, there is an italic in `Language methods`

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work in ST3. Are you sure you have the proper color scheme selected? After you made the change, did you save the file, restart Sublime, and open a new buffer or file to test it?

Comment: I did. The only other interaction I can think about is that I have sublimelinter installed which may have some interaction as well?